# Randomly construct linear combination that is within bounds over two basis

Tags: linear-algebra, monte-carlo

Given rank deficient matrix $A$, I want to randomly construct vectors $\vec{x}$ such that:

1. $0 \le x_{j} \le 1$
2. $0 \le b_{j} \le 1$ where $\vec{b} = A\vec{x}$

Matrix $A$ is about 10 x 15. I want to generate $10^{5}$ $\vec{x}$ as an initial guess in each iteration of a solver.

Below is my attempts.

---

*Least square and rejection*

1. Generate $\vec{y}$ with entries between 0 and 1.
2. Generate $\vec{b}$ with entries between 0 and 1.
3. Minimize $(\vec{y} - \vec{x})^{2}$ subjected to constraint $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$.
4. Reject $\vec{x}$ that are out of bounds.

Problem: the rejection rate is very high. Very impractical even for a 10 x 15 matrix $A$.

Step 2 is equivalent to solving

$\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
I & A^{T}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{x}\\
\vec{\lambda}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{b}\\
\vec{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

---

*Constrained Optimization*

- Generate random $\vec{y}$ within bounds.
- Objective: $(\vec{x} - \vec{y})^2$.
- Constraint: $A\vec{x} = b$
- Bounds: between 0 and 1.

Problem: Optimization is too slow and often gives result out of bounds. Impractical.

---

*Other ideas*

- Null space
- Simplex, random planes, and projection
- Hit and run sampling

Comment: You want to find a random point in a polytope. There are known algorithms for this.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Requirement 1 = cube. Requirement 2 = parallelepiped. Intersection =  convex ploytope. Which kind of polytope should I google?

Comment: Found solution for convex polytope with barycentric coordinate. Thanks!

Comment: But the method with barycentric coordinate is not uniform sampling. For each $A$ and $\vec{b}$, the polytope that bounds $\vec{x}$ is different. Since I only need one point for each polytope, hit-and-run sampling might need quite a few iterations to spread to all space within the polytope.

Comment: There are methods that work for *any* polytope.

Answer (score 1):

Using barycentric coordinate and keeping sum of coordinate equal to 1 do not sample a convex polytope uniformly.

[image: Barycentric_coordinate_sampling]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000000  # Number of samples
V = 5 # Generate points within a V-gon

# generate columns that each sum to 1
s = np.exp(-np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(V, N)))
s /= s.sum(axis=0)

# generate vertex of regular polygon
r = 2
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, V+1)[1:]
v_x = r*np.cos(theta)
v_y = r*np.sin(theta)

# generate random points within the polygon
# by linear combination of coordinates of
# vetex where the coefficients sum to 1.
x = (v_x[:, np.newaxis] * s).sum(axis=0)
y = (v_y[:, np.newaxis] * s).sum(axis=0)

# plot density
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)
extent = [-r, r, -r, r]

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower')
plt.plot(v_x, v_y, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: A good observation. Usually, the simplest algorithm to implement is rejection sampling and its performance is often acceptable.